Angular wrapper for vanillaJS components
I have a problem where I need to create angular wrappers for already made vanillaJS components. I have the following folder structure
/foo
├── /lib
│   ├── /core
│   └── /angular
│       └── /project
│            ├── tsconfig.json
│            ├── angular.json
│            ├── node_modules/
│
├── tsconfig.json
├── node_modules
....

I want to use the components/classes in /core folder inside the angular project, however I get an error when i use ng build project
File '/lib/core/components/MilestoneBar/models/MilestoneBarProps.ts' is not under 'rootDir' '/Users/user/work/foo/lib/angular/projects/production/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
My idea is to use the files that are in core as my src files in the angular components.
ex:
import { ExampleComponent as ExampleCoreComponent } from '../../lib/core';
private exampleInstance: ExampleCoreComponent<any> | undefined;

I appreciate all help that is given. Thank you in advance!
I already tried changing the root dir in the tsconfig.json ( the one that is inside the angular folder )
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "rootDir": "../../",
...
}



Did you try setting up paths in your tsconfig for your lib?

@JSONDerulo yes I tried and that didn't work, same error
